# How do I set up a second Mercurial respository on SourceForge?

Tags: linux, unix, mercurial, sourceforge

I have been trying to create a second Mercurial repository on SourceForge following the instructions [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Mercurial#CreatingMultipleRepositories).

Here's the grand total of what I did after logging in to the interactive shell:

```
[myuser@shell-23010 project]$ pwd
/home/scm_hg/p/pr/project
[myuser@shell-23010 project]$ mkdir newrepo
[myuser@shell-23010 project]$ hg init newrepo
[myuser@shell-23010 project]$ chmod -R g+w newrepo
[myuser@shell-23010 project]$ cd newrepo
[myuser@shell-23010 newrepo]$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser   root 2048 Jun 25 20:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 dummy    root 2048 Jun 25 20:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser   root 2048 Jun 25 20:37 .hg
[myuser@shell-23010 newrepo]$ cd .hg
[myuser@shell-23010 .hg]$ ls -al
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser   root 2048 Jun 25 20:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 myuser   root 2048 Jun 25 20:37 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser   root   57 Jun 25 20:37 00changelog.i
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser   root   23 Jun 25 20:37 requires
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser   root 2048 Jun 25 20:37 store
[myuser@shell-23010 .hg]$
```

So far, so good. However:

- When trying to clone the `newrepo` to my local machine, I get this lame response:

  ```
  PS C:\Users\myuser\temp> hg clone ssh://myuser@hg.code.sf.net/p/project/newrepo local-newrepo
  remote: abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!
  abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
  ```
- Furthermore, `newrepo` does not show up under the Mercurial menu or page of my SF project page.

What step am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the answer is: don't use the SourceForge docs! The [link](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Mercurial#CreatingMultipleRepositories) I gave above gives utterly the wrong directions!

The repository I created above is cloneable from the URL `hg clone ssh://<user>@project.hg.sourceforge.net/hgroot/project/newrepo`. HOWEVER, it isn't linked to the SourceForge project page in any way -- it seems to be a deprecated location and no one has removed the stale doc.

The correct way is to go into the "Admin" tab on your SF project page, then pick the "Tools" option on the left-hand menu, then pick the "Mercurial" option under "Click to Install".

Comme ça: [image]

And just like that, it's done!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the two-letter `pr` part of the path. That is, you should specify .../p/**pr**/project/newrepo in the 'clone' command.

Comment: Are you referring to the clone attempt? I also tried `hg clone ssh://myuser@hg.code.sf.net/p/pr/project/newrepo local-newrepo` and got the same response. Also that wouldn't explain the secondary issue (why doesn't the repo show up on my project page)?

Comment: Yes, I meant the clone command. And shouldn't there be also `hgroot` part just after `.sf.net`? as for the second part - I'm not sure about SF, but it may depend upon settings in .hgrc of whether the repository is visible or not (at least publishing through `hgweb` depends on it).

Comment: I think you're right in principle. Sadly the overarching problem is that the doc I was using was stale! See above. Thx for the help :)